# using XMPP or WebSocket, why there is a server needed in real-time communication between users?

Tags: xmpp, websocket, chat, real-time

At the bottom, it's all about socket communications. If there is some way to get the ip of the both users, why can't the connection be directly setup between the users instead of having to go thru a server in the middle?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My 2 cents:

No one out there forces us to have a server based real-time communication model. Infact XMPP have an extension called ["Serverless Messaging"](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html) which defines how to communicate over local or wide-area networks using the principles of zero-configuration networking for endpoint discovery and the syntax of XML streams and XMPP messaging for real-time communication. This method uses DNS-based Service Discovery and Multicast DNS to discover entities that support the protocol, including their IP addresses and preferred ports.

P2P chat applications have been for over a decade now. Having a server in the middle is purely a decision dependent upon your application needs. If your application can live with chats getting lost while the user was transitioning between online/offline status, then you can very well have a direct P2P model going. Similarly, there are a loads and loads of advantages (contact list management, avatars, entity discovery, presence authorization, offline messages, ....) when it comes to choosing a server based messaging model. If you try to have all this right inside your P2P based clients, they might die or under-perform because of all the work they will need to perform by themselves.

"WebSockets" were not designed for P2P/Serverless communication, rather they were designed to provide a standardized PUSH semantic over stateless HTTP protocol. In short, "WebSockets" is a standardized way replacing hacky comet, long-polling, chunked-encoding, jsonp, iframe-based and various other technique developers have been using to simulate server push over HTTP.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I will add that comparing XMPP to websocket is like comparing a car to a road.  Once the WebSocket spec is solidified

Comment: @Robin That really depends whether by XMPP you mean RFC 6120 or RFC 6121. XMPP-Core (6120) defines just a stream protocol and datagram format - exactly like WebSocket protocol. In your analogy, both are roads. It is XMPP-IM (6121) that defines stanza format and meaning. There is even RFC 7395 defining how to "drive" XMPP-IM over WebSocket instead XMPP-Core.

Answer (score 3):

Named WebSockets (if someday it is fully and widely supported) could be the solution.

http://namedwebsockets.github.io/spec/

> Named WebSockets are useful in a variety of collaborative local device
>   and local network scenarios: *Discover matching peer services on the
>   local device and/or the local network*.

Answer (score 0):

Direct communication between users is possible in Peer To Peer (P2P) networks. In P2P each participant can act as client as well as server. But for P2P networks you need to write a separate program to make the communication possible.

Web Sockets let you leverage existing common browsers as clients. All depends on what is the purpose of your application and how you want to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets don't allow the socket to listen for connections, only to connect as a client to a server (not reverse). Technically they could make it allow this, but as far as I understand the spec doesn't currently (nor is it expected to) allow listen functionality for WebSockets.

The new WebRTC (http://www.webrtc.org/) spec looks like it might support peer-to-peer connections. I have not played with WebRTC at all so I'm not in a position to comment on it. I think it would be a bit more involved than WebSocket stuff. Maybe someone who knows WebRTC better can chime in. (Also apart from the latest version of Chrome I'm not sure if any of the other browsers really support WebRTC yet).

Comment: then the device themselves could be the server as well, couldn't they?

Comment: Yes (from what I understand), using WebRTC, two users should be able to connect to each other and communicate completely independent of any other party (ie. a server). But as I noted the browser support is limited currently. There are some demo apps using it out there, including some video chat stuff using Jingle (P2P audio/video extension to XMPP).

Answer (score 0):

> If there is some way to get the ip of the both users

You nailed the answer right in your question.

Most machines I use have IP address of `192.168.0.10` (or similar from `192.168.` private network) and are deep, deep behind several layers of [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). With the end of free IPv4 address pool and IPv6 nowhere near sight, this is the reality most users live. Having a stable intermediary of known, *routable* address helps a ton working around this issue.